Answering new users questions
Just a thought: A way to encourage new users to keep returning to the site would be to prioritize answering these questions over the regular users. 
What do you think?
I have asked a truckload of questions and plan to answer the ones that sit for too long unanswered.

I would say to do both - an example, my 'routine' of sorts is:

Check the review lists
Check meta
Check the recent questions
Check the unanswered lists
Maybe write a question


Just to summarise - my own personal preference is to answer questions first before I answer one.

I think you meant to say your preference is to answer a question before you ask one, right?

@what yes, that.. typing while sleep deprived, sometimes it gets me.

Well, you know where your bed is ... ;-)

@what, yes I do, however sleep is not possible when the pain kicks in.

I'm sorry to hear that, @Damien. Hope you get better quickly.

@what thank you for that - but what I have won't get better, but thankfully won't get worse.
